# Expand in factor when even and odd power is given

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please expand or factorize $A^n$ + $B^n$ for odd integer n as well as even integer n?

This is may be small question, for me it is something big. Kindly do it...

Comment: for $n=2$ there is no factorization unless you go with imaginary numbers $(A+Bi)(A-Bi)$

Answer (score 1):

if $A$ and $B$ are both nonzero, you can write $x=\frac{A}{B}$ and focus on the factorization of $x^n+1$, recovering the full factorization by finally multiplying by  $B^n$.

as ratchet freak remarks, the factorization depends on which field you are working in. if you are in $\mathbb{C}$ the factorization of $x^n - 1$, which is well-known - look up *cyclotomic polynomials* - can be utilized by first multiplying $x$ by a primitive $n^{th}$ root of minus $1$.

in $\mathbb{R}$ the possibilities are more restricted, though you do know (as i have just noticed that Robert has already pointed out) that $x+1$ always divides $x^n+1$, so if $n$ is a compound number (i.e. not prime) that implies that $x^n+1$ will be divisible by $x^m+1$ whenever $m$ is a proper factor of $n$

Comment: ... and $n/m$ is odd.  Not true if it's even.

Comment: thank you Robert, and sorry Rock for missing that. i will not edit my post, so that it will be there to serve me as an awful reminder of my sloppiness - not that i haven't many such reminders already, but a fresh instance is always good for the soul! still, per ardua ad astram!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: If $n = k m$ where $k$ is odd, $A^m + B^m$ is a factor.